# Little known late 80s fantasy show, Vytor the Star Fire Champion; any details?

Tags: cartoon, fantasy-genre

I was 8 or so when this show came out. I was lucky enough to record the first episode, and have held onto it for decades. [**Vytor: The Star Fire Champion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vytor:_The_Starfire_Champion) tells the story of a teenage warrior from a whole other galaxy, where magic and technology exist. It used burgeoning graphic technology that became very popular with shows like *Denver: The Last Dinosaur, Mr. Bogus* and *Widget the World Watcher* to animate the landscape and space battles. To my knowledge, only 4 or 5 episodes were ever made, but the voice cast included Peter "Optimus Prime" Cullen.

The story (as told by Vytor's spirit guide and maternal figure, Lyria) goes as follows:

In a distant galaxy, a world is ruled by 3 kings:

- Al-tare, the King of Science and Knowledge, ruler of the floating Cloud nation;
- Myzor, the King of War and ruler of an island continent of robots and warriors;
- Tryon, the King of Justice, regent of most of the freelands.

For some reason, King Myzor grew hungry for power, and seized the Saturn Orb, supposedly "one of the most powerful energy sources in the universe."  With it, Myzor plotted total domination of the entire galaxy. Al-Tare wanted nothing to do with it, and kept his people separate from the ensuing conflict. But the courageous King Tryon directly opposed Myzor; he managed to steal the Starfire Ring and separate it from the Orb, putting the Orb to sleep and greatly diminishing its power. Tryon and his followers were arrested for his heroism, and cast into the shadow realm (another dimensional plain of existence outside our reality, accessible only by the power of the Orb) for punishment, but not before he managed to hide the Ring with his infant son. Myzor then began a search for the mystically powerful Starfire Ring, which lasted for 17 years.

All that time, an orphaned Vytor was hidden amongst the Terran people, a peace-loving tribal culture very close to an approximation of both Native American & Polynesian islanders. He trained for years to become their "Village champion," alongside his best friend and rival Tarfiel. On the day their final contest, to decide who would be champion and thus protect the village from "best and fow," was to be decided, Myzor sent some of his Mutoid robots on yet another mission searching for the Starfire Ring. They brought down a Cloud Cruiser from the floating city which belonged to Princess Skyla, daughter of Al-Tare and a scientific and gadgeteer prodigy, thinking her distance from their protected city was somewhat suspect.

This eventually lead to Vytor and Skyla meeting, their finding Lyria's chamber and learning the truth of their linked destiny. Here, Vytor also gains his incredible weapon of power: The Starfire Shield, a mystically powered defensive and offensive tool energized by the ring on his chest which responds to his every command.

Research brought to light that all the episodes were collected on a DVD set, and even put forth on YouTube for public viewing, but no other information is available about the property.

**Question:** I was wondering if anyone knew any other details about the property, if it perhaps would be relaunched? Or if there were any follow up stories to it (comic books, author notes, etc.)?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Vytor-Starfire-Champion-Peter-Cullen/dp/B000FA5EVU

Comment: I've contacted the right-holders. My gut instinct is "no", but we'll have to see ;-)

Comment: @Valorum Wow...you are amazing, V. thank you. I just saw a lot of promise in this series, and with all the retoolings and reboots being made, wanted to bring some attention to it so others might be able to enjoy it as well. Perhaps even do something new with it, given the opportunity.

Comment: There is also a Wikipedia page at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vytor:_The_Starfire_Champion, albeit not really terribly informative other than saying that, due to the cost of the episodes (which included CG at a time when that was expensive) and the lack of a toyline, there were very few episodes made.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'm aware of the wikipedia page, but thank you for bringing it up here for others, friend. As you said...not terribly informative. I do remember the graphics being excellent for the time, and the story wasn't too bad either. Could use a little more representation, but other than that, it seemed to be a stellar start to a new sci-fi series.

Comment: Incidentally, can you identify the specific question you want answered? I think it's "Are there any plans for a rerelease or a reboot?" but it's not clear.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I kept the question at the end, with "any other details about the property, if it perhaps would be relanched or if there were any follow up stories to it". I thought there may have been a continuation, a fan site, a comic book, a creator's blog, **anything** that gave some more information on the series.